# How to install QGIS on a 2006 iMac?

Tags: qgis, mac

I would like to know if there is QGIS version for a 32bit Mac (Intel Duo core processor). The newer versions require a 64bit processor.

Comment: Might be useful links according to the question  http://people.umass.edu/nrc297s/PDFs/Installing_QGIS_on_a_Mac.pdf

Comment: http://multimedia.journalism.berkeley.edu/blog/2011/oct/6/qgis-tips/

Comment: use parallels to create a windows environment? http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/

Comment: Have you checked out kyngchaos? He has an archive of older versions of QGIS for Mac if you need them. There is no support for most of the older versions though. http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/archive

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by *danagerous*, kyngchaos keeps an archive of past versions:
http://kyngchaos.com/software/archive

QGIS 1.7.0-3 runs on my Macbook Pro 1,1 (32-bit Intel Core Duo) with Snow Leopard (10.6.8).

Alternatively, I've had success compiling QGIS 1.8 using MacPorts:
http://www.macports.org/

It took a while to build all the dependencies, but once it's done you end up with a `QGIS.app` in `/Applications/MacPorts`.